# Editing a gpx file inside iOS application

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, file, gpx

I am trying to make an app that locks my GPS to my current location until I disable it. I have a location.gpx file in the same location as the main.storyboard and ViewController.swift, etc. is. 
Plan is that the gpx file is locked to run in the schemes and set the iPhone location to the gpx location. When I click Unfreeze it'd edit the file lat and Lon to "". And when I freeze it they edit to the lat and Lon coordinates I am currently in.

The question is how can I edit the location.gpx file inside the ViewController.swift program? I have already done all the buttons and stuff. All I need is the knowledge to edit that gpx file.

iOS 13.3.1 and macOS Catalina 10.15.3, Xcode 11.3.1.

Comment: It's XML. The spec is readily available (e.g. https://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/). What's the question?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the open sourced library CoreGPX https://github.com/vincentneo/CoreGPX to manipulate GPX files in iOS.

Here's how you can do it:

Firstly, at the library to your project.
Don't forget to `import CoreGPX`

Secondly, parse the GPX file like this:

```
guard let yourFile = GPXParser(withURL: <insert location.gpx URL here>)?.parsedData() else { return }
```

Lastly,
you can now access and modify the GPX instance like this:

```
// Print all way points coordinates of your file
for waypoint in yourFile.waypoints {
   print("Latitude: \(waypoint.latitude!)")
   print("Longitude: \(waypoint.longitude!)")
}

// Add a way point to GPX instance
let newPoint = GPXWaypoint(latitude: 1.33456, longitude: -1.36881) 
yourFile.add(waypoint: newPoint)

// Export the above modified instance as new GPX file
do {
   yourFile.outputToFile(saveAt: <insert URL here>, fileName: "location")
}
catch {
   print(error)
}
```

Note/Disclosure: I created the CoreGPX library, but I'm recommending it to you as I feel that you could use it well for your use case.